# HTML/CSS Obfuscation Compiling

Tags: html, css, obfuscation

I have a question about obfuscate the final output of an HTML and CSS file.
Lets stay I have this HTML code below with the corresponding class names declared in a separate CSSfile:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="session-info"></div>
</div> 

<div class="bank-account-content">
  <div class="account-info"></div>
  <div class="account-info"></div>
  <div class="here-is-my-ss-number"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to take my HTML/CSS file and process it in a way that it will take original class names/ids in a HTML/CSS file and randomly generate new files to replace the existing class names/ids with meaningless class names/ids to obscure the final output? For example, The above output would be processed and result in the html shown below with a corresponding style sheet that has the abstracted class/id names defined.

```
<div class="1dcx4y">
  <div class="1354fs"></div>
  <div class="f3wecd"></div>
</div> 

<div class="retv5">
  <div class="dgee2f></div>
  <div class="fhg54h"></div>
  <div class="dgd426"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this: [https://github.com/bitstrider/obscure](https://github.com/bitstrider/obscure)

Comment: try: http://www.zeroify.com/

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/munch

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try http://www.cssobfuscator.com/:

> **What it does:**
>   - It will take your CSS file, apply minification, encoding and encypting and finally injects this unreadable crap into tailored JS library (also obfuscated).
>   - The result you will get is this tailored (unique) library, containing obfuscated CSS. Just include it in the place of the original CSS.
>   **What it does not:**
>   - It will not speed up displaying of your web.
>   - It will not hide CSS rules in inspector (developer's tools) - but it don't mind, attacker will probably not copy all stuff by one rule.

Or <s>http://htmlmuncher.com/</s>: (Dead link, [Github repository](https://github.com/ccampbell/html-muncher))

> HTML Muncher is a command line utility written in Python that rewrites classes and ids in CSS, HTML, and JavaScript files in order to save precious bytes and obfuscate your code.
>   **How it Works**
>   1. You pass in a list of CSS, HTML, and JavaScript files to be rewritten
>   2. The CSS and JavaScript files are scanned to find any class and id references
>   3. The classes and ids are mapped to new classes and ids with 1 or 2 letter names (a, b, c ... aa, ab, ac ...)
>   4. The files are rewritten with the new class and id names and saved to a new location on disk

Comment: Your second link is the right one, I think. The first tool is not very useful (it’s easy to break, it requires JavaScript, it doesn’t allow `@media`, it wants to host it itself without HTTPS support…).

Comment: Link is broken for HTMLMuncher - so find it here on Github: https://github.com/ccampbell/html-muncher

Comment: It removes the unused css? Thanks.