# What kind of tools / generator are used for shortening css class selector?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have come across this [bootstrap theme](https://bootstrap-themes.github.io/application/profile/index.html) and just wondering what tools are they using to simplify / shorten the class selector name?

Instead of something like:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

It's using:

```
<div class="qx">
  <div class="qv"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

> Google's [Closure Stylesheets](http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/) can rename your class names. It work
>   in conjunction with [Closure Template](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/) for the HTML and [Closure
>   Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) for the JavaScript.
>
> > Closure Stylesheets makes it possible to rename CSS class names in the generated stylesheet, which helps reduce the size of the CSS that
> >     is sent down to your users. Of course, this is not particularly useful
> >     unless the class names are renamed consistently in the HTML and
> >     JavaScript files that use the CSS. Fortunately, you can use the
> >     Closure Compiler to update the class names in your JavaScript and
> >     Closure Templates to update the class names in your HTML.

SOURCE: [HTML/CSS Obfuscation Compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262589/html-css-obfuscation-compiling)

Comment: i don't think it's using that